# NodeJS crashing chrome browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome

Nodejs application developed with ExpressJS and pkg to build executable. It opens a chrome application window and the application runs perfectly on development machine. Once nodejs application is running, a second copy can be started in chrome browser tab by referencing localhost.

On my brother's machine running the exact same Windows 11 and exact same version of chrome, the chrome application window opens and then closes in a few seconds without any error message or chrome crash log. However, if he opens the chrome browser window before starting the nodejs application, the nodejs chrome application window opens and the applications runs correctly.

We uninstalled his antivirus program to eliminate this potential problem caused by antivirus programand the uninstall had no affect on the failure. I don't think it a memory problem since it runs successfully if the chrome browser window is opened first.
We reinstalled chrome to make sure that we were running the same exact chrome code.

Any ideas where the problem might be?

Comment: `Any ideas where the problem might be?` in your code